# OSMNX not finding the json files saved

Tags: python, osmnx

I had to reinstall anaconda and with that several python packages. I then installed anaconda again and the osmnx package. However when I try to run some code where the program is supposed to get the data from a cache folder it keeps trying to download it again. Could someone tell me why?

Here is the code:

import osmnx as ox

```
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cahce=True, cache_folder = '/home/diogo_mota/Dropbox/Diogo_Rede_simetria/MAIN_CACHE')

cities = ox.geocode_to_gdf(['Município de Lisboa', 'Município de Oeiras', 'Município da Amadora', 'Município de Loures', 'Município de Odivelas'])
```

I know the path to the folder is correct. I tried one other thing: created a new empty folder, downloaded the data the first time the code ran, and then re ran the code. This time it did load the cache files. Why can't it recognize the other folder that has a previous version of the network? (I need this specific version and not the new one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the OSMnx package's change log, the cache's hashing algorithm changed between the 0.x and 1.x versions. To use cache files generated by a 0.x version of the package, you must use a 0.x version. As stated [here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/526):

> The caching hash algorithm was changed for v1.0, invalidating old caches made with prior releases.